# change background color of p with javascript depending on result

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, object

I need to change the background color of a result in a p tag, if the result of a variable is > then 1.
I guess this could be accomplished with a if statement maybe?
This is the code I am working with:

```
const todos = [{
  text: 'Order airline tickets',
  completed: false
},{
  text: 'Vaccine appointment',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'Order Visa',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'Book hotell',
  completed: false
}, {
  text: 'Book taxi to airport',
  completed: true
}]

const filters = {
  searchText: ''
}

const renderTodos = function (todos, filters) {

  //use filter method for the title search string and save it to filters variable
    const filteredTodos = todos.filter(function (todo) {
        return todo.text.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase())
    })

    const notDone = filteredTodos.filter(function (todo) {
      return !todo.completed
    })

    //Empty the div containg the result, this has to be between filter and the display of the result
    document.querySelector('#todos').innerHTML = ''

    const summary = document.createElement('h4')
    summary.textContent = `You found ${notDone.length} hits on this search that are not complete`
    document.querySelector('#todos').appendChild(summary)



    //loop through note object, create a p tag for the title searched and append to the div
    filteredTodos.forEach(function (todo) {
        const noteEl = document.createElement('p')
        noteEl.textContent = todo.text
        document.querySelector('#todos').appendChild(noteEl)

    })
    elem = document.createElement("hr")
    document.querySelector('#todos').appendChild(elem)
}

document.querySelector('#search-todo').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  filters.searchText = e.target.value
  renderTodos(todos, filters)
})
```

So the result of the search, if there are also !todo.completed in the p tags that I am appending to my #todos div, only those p tags should have a p background color of yellow.

thanks

Comment: Yes, that should be possible - but what exactly is not working with the given code?

Comment: I am quite new to js, the code is working fine, but I would like to learn how to change the background color of the p tags that have a status of false (taks that are not completed) when doing the filtering of the strings.
So only the p tags that are not completed get the background color of yellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this `if` statement inside the `forEach` loop:

```
if (!todo.completed) {
    noteEl.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

The full loop should look like this:

```
filteredTodos.forEach(function (todo) {
    const noteEl = document.createElement('p');
    noteEl.textContent = todo.text;
    if (!todo.completed) {
        noteEl.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    document.querySelector('#todos').appendChild(noteEl);
})
```

Comment: No problem @user2371684